# StaticResource for Application Bar Background Color - WP8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, appbar

I would like to use the default Background color of the Application Bar as a background color for another panel.

I tried to find a StaticResource for it but no luck.
Is there such a static resource? What is the default bacground color that the app bar uses?

Comment: It seems that ApplicationBar Background doesn't have default value : [see Remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbar.backgroundcolor%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) ?

Comment: @har07, thanks. Where does it get its color from in that case?

Comment: Just pull out its control template and look. If you're in VS2012+ just right-click->edit template->edit a copy or use Blend in the same way.